# Getting same values for different keys in Hashmap

Tags: java, android, arraylist, hashmap

I have implemented hashmap in which I have assigned received json object to some strings like rvalue,price,dsvalue and passing those string as an value with keys KEY_EXTRA, KEY_PLEVEL, KEY_DISTANCE.Then I pass and add this hashmap to arraylist .I have defined cutom view for each item of listview where I want to set these values like rating,distance. when I use this data to set text of textview it uses value of only KEY_DISTANCE for all other textview as text.Values of rvalue,price,dsvalue are distinct.

Initialization:

```
     public static String KEY_REFERENCE = "reference"; // id of the place
     public static String KEY_NAME = "name"; // name of the place
     public static String KEY_VICINITY = "vicinity"; // Place area name
     public static String KEY_EXTRA ;// Place area name
     public static String KEY_PLEVEL ;
     public static String KEY_DISTANCE;
```

Below is the hashmap code:

```
          if(status.equals("OK")){
                    // Successfully got places details
                    if (nearPlaces.results != null) {
                        // loop through each place
                        for (Place p : nearPlaces.results) {

                            String rvalue="-NA-";
                            String price="-NA-";


                            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                            double rate=p.rating;
                             rvalue = String.valueOf(rate);
                            //Log.d("Rating",rvalue );
                            double latitude = p.geometry.location.lat;
                            double longitude = p.geometry.location.lng;
                            Location selected_location=new Location("locationA");
                            selected_location.setLatitude(userlat);
                            selected_location.setLongitude(userlng);
                        Location near_locations=new Location("locationA");
                            near_locations.setLatitude(latitude);
                            near_locations.setLongitude(longitude);

                        double distance=selected_location.distanceTo(near_locations);
                        double dvalue=(Math.round(distance));
                         String dsvalue = String.valueOf(dvalue)
     // Place reference is used to get "place full details"
                            map.put(KEY_REFERENCE, p.reference);

                            // Place name
                            map.put(KEY_NAME, p.name);


                            map.put(KEY_EXTRA,rvalue);
                             price= p.price_level;
                            map.put(KEY_PLEVEL,price);
                            placesListItems.add(map);
                       //    Log.d("price level",price);

                        map.put(KEY_DISTANCE, dsvalue+" M");
                            placesListItems.add(map);



                        }

                        // list adapter
                        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(nearby_mainactivity.this, placesListItems,
                                R.layout.list_item,
                                new String[] { KEY_REFERENCE, KEY_NAME, KEY_EXTRA, KEY_PLEVEL, KEY_DISTANCE}, new int[] {
                                        R.id.reference, R.id.name, R.id.textView3,R.id.textView5 ,R.id.textView7});

                        // Adding data into listview
                        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Here is the xml layout of view of the each litview item:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" 
>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="70dp" >

    <TextView android:id="@+id/reference"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:layout_width="265dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:padding="10dip"
    android:textSize="16dip"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/name"
    android:text="Rating : "
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView3"
     android:textStyle="bold"
    android:text="Price Level : "
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/name"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView2"


    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView4"


    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView7"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView6"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView6"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView6"

    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView6"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView5"
     android:textStyle="bold"
    android:text="Distance : "
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: can you post the initialization of the KEY_* constants?

Comment: heyy friend see I hav posted Initialization

Comment: where you initialize : KEY_EXTRA,KEY_PLEVEL and KEY_DISTANCE ?

Comment: Thanx guyz.Initialization worked.

Comment: Since we're in the world of object-oriented programming, wouldn't it make a *lot* more sense to define a simple POJO to describe the data you're currently pushing into a `Map`? That is, creating a `Place` class with relevant fields, setters and getters would not only improve your code syntactically and semantically, but also make it much easier to debug. Just a thought.